# Как анимировать border вокруг круглой кнопки?

Tags: css, css-animation

Есть кнопка с бордером:

[image: Кнопка закрытия]

При наведении на кнопку, бордер должен прокрутиться на 360 градусов, при этом сама кнопка должна оставаться неподвижной. Вот код:

```css
.menu__button_animat {
    background-image: conic-gradient( #755efc 90deg, #fff 90deg 175deg, #755efc 150deg );
}
.menu__button-close {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    border: none;
    background: #F8F6FF url(https://i.ibb.co/JnNj5GZ/Icon-2.png) center no-repeat;
    z-index: 100;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
}
.mega-menu__circle-border {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.mega-menu__circle-border:after {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
}
.menu__button_animat:hover  {
    animation: progress 1s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes progress {
    100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="mega-menu__circle-border menu__button_animat ">
  <button class="menu__button-close "></button>
</div>
```

Саму иконку прописывала через `::before`, всё равно вращение кнопки остаётся. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что упускаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы что-то намудрили с разметкой и стилями, всё можно было сделать проще. Но если оставить Ваш вариант, то надо "крестику" добавить такую же анимацию, только в обратном направлении - тогда визуально будет казаться, что он стоит на месте, а крутится обводка:

```css
.menu__button_animat {
    background-image: conic-gradient( #755efc 90deg, #fff 90deg 175deg, #755efc 150deg );
}
.menu__button-close {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    border: none;
    background: #F8F6FF url(https://i.ibb.co/JnNj5GZ/Icon-2.png) center no-repeat;
    z-index: 100;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
}
.mega-menu__circle-border {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.mega-menu__circle-border:after {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
}
.menu__button_animat:hover  {
    animation: progress 1s linear forwards;
}
.menu__button_animat:hover .menu__button-close {
  animation: antiprogress 1s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes progress {
    100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes antiprogress {
    100% {transform:rotate(-360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="mega-menu__circle-border menu__button_animat">
    <button class="menu__button-close"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Чтобы проиграть анимацию в обратном направлении вместо `forward` можно добавить `reverse` в css `.menu__button_animat:hover .menu__button-close { animation: progress 1s linear reverse; }`

Comment: @Rudi, `forwards` нужен для сохранения состояния анимации после завершения. В данном конкретном случае кажется, что это подходит, потому что поворот осуществляется на 360 градусов, и откат визуально не заметен. Но если бы поворот был на 45 градусов, то reverse вместо forwards не прокатил бы.

Comment: "В данном конкретном случае", автор указал "При наведении на кнопку, этот бордер должен прокрутиться на 360 градусов" Я лишь дополнил возможный вариант "В данном конкретном случае".

Comment: @Danila, Да, есть у меня такая проблема мудрить и усложнять... А в данном примере намудрила с чем? псевдо элементы?

Comment: @Александра, наоборот: можно было обойтись псевдоэлементом для кнопки, без дива. И вращать только псевдоэлемент.

Comment: @Danila, действительно! переделала, как вы сказали! спасибо!)